# How to format and use historical traffic data and to create a traffic enabled network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, traffic

I have speed factors for road segments collected at time intervals of one hour daily for a whole week. But I dont know how to format the data so that I can relate it with my digitised road segments in ArcGIS and later create a traffic enabled network.

Comment: Have you looked at Esri help page on traffic data? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0047000001rt000000

Comment: yes, i have looked at it but all it does is explain how data works but not how to format and configure it

Comment: Take a look at the data provided in the Network Analyst tutorial, you'll see how it is supposed to be formatted.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.